# push and pop operations in a leaf function

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, nasm

The following is a an x86 assembly language subroutine, written by me, meant to be called from a C program:

```
;================================================================
; IsBetweenAandB - tests a character if it is between 'a' and 'b'
; arguments:
;   ch = character to be tested
;   a = start character
;   b = end character
; return value:
;   1 = yes
;   0 = no
;----------------------------------------------------------------
IsBetweenAandB:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp    
    add esp, 12 ;<------------------------------------------(1)
                        ; [ebp]     = old ebp stack frame
                        ; [ebp + 4] = return address
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]  ; [ebp+8] = ch
    push ebx ;<------------------------------------------(2)
    mov ebx, [ebp + 12] ; 'a' = start
    push edx ;<------------------------------------------(2)
    mov edx, [ebp + 16] ; 'e' = end 

    cmp eax, ebx    ; compare 'ch' with 'a'
    jae next_test_ibab  ; if(ch>='a')
    jb  set_zero_ibab   ; if(ch<'a')

next_test_ibab:
    cmp eax, edx    ; compare 'ch' with 'e'
    jbe set_one_ibab        ; if(ch<='e')
    ja  set_zero_ibab   ; if(ch>'e')

set_one_ibab:
    mov eax, 1  
    jmp returns_ibab

set_zero_ibab:
    mov eax, 0

returns_ibab:
    pop edx ;<------------------------------------------(2)
    pop ebx ;<------------------------------------------(2)

    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

I have two questions here:

1. Since, I am not using any local variable here, do I need to write **`add esp, 12`**?
2. (a) Are these pushes and pops actually necessary at all (these are intended for restoring the old values of **`ebx`** and **`edx`** registers)?
   (b) Would they create any disturbance in `esp`?

Comment: Pretty sure that both answers are no

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, there are three questions under the source code.

Comment: The problem is that eax, ecx and edx need not be saved but ebx has to be. If you can work out code that only uses eax, ecx, edx you don't need any stack manipulation

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, hmm....got it.

Comment: BTW this can be written in something like 5 instructions exploiting just eax and maybe a single scratch register (say, ecx).

Comment: @MatteoItalia, let pass my lab test first. optimization comes later :)

Comment: @user366312: the point is, if you keep it simple you can avoid headaches with the stack ;-) Something like this https://pastebin.com/uE5wqmJF

Comment: `add esp, 12` seems wrong anyway as the stack goes down.  What is this supposed to do?

Comment: @fuz, i guessed so. I just wanted to be confirmed.

Comment: @fuz, 1st I thought 3 bytes are being allocated for 3 arguments. Later I understood that 3 bytes should be allocated only if we want to create 3 local variables.

Comment: @user366312 The point is, the stack grows downwards.  So to allocate stack space, you need to decrement, not increment the stack pointer.  Incrementing the stack pointer instead releases stack space, which does not seem to be what you want.